# Obtener datos de Consulta vía http Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Estoy aprendiendo algo de Angular y Ionic.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
lista: Trabajadores[]; 

obtenerTrabajadores(id) {
this.servicio.getTrabajadores(id)
    .subscribe(
      rs => this.lista = rs,
      er => console.log(er),
      () => console.log(this.lista) //Aqui me muestra los datos 
    )} console.log(this.lista) // Aqui no me muestra nada
```

La idea es traer los datos de los trabajadores los cuales tienen los campos longitud y latitud y montarlos en un mapa de Google.

La función trae los datos y puedo verlos en el archivo html haciendo esto

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of lista">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.last_name }}
</ion-row>
```

pero como necesito los datos para cargar el mapa intento hacer lo mismo en el archivo .ts y realmente no se como ponerlos en la variable. pensé que si declaraba la variable lista de manera global podría pero no.

De antemano gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo hacer un par de cambios:

En la clase :

```
class Clase {

    lista : Observable<Trabajadores[]>;

    // Constructor, funciones, etc.

    obtenerTrabajadores(id){
        this.lista = this.servicio.getTrabajadores(id);
        this.lista.subscribe(
            ()=> {
                // Cargar mapa aquí
            }
        )
    }

    ...
```

También podría usar el método do (del Observable)

```
this.lista = this.servicio.getTrabajadores(id)
    .do(funcCargarMapa, funcErr, funcFinally)
```

En el documento HTML (Nótese el uso del pipe `async`):

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of lista | async">
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.last_name }}
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, solucionado el tema